# integrating wordpress plugins to work together

Tags: wordpress, plugins

First of all a big thank you to this community. So helpful and I would not know what to do without the help here. Which is probably the reason why I post WP questions here.

My question is of general nature therefore I'm posting here. I've already tried posting to the respective plugin forums and WPExchange and just not getting any hits.

In wordpress when I'm working with multiple plugins how are they integrated to work together so that it's seamless. For example I'm using 2 plugins: One is a Classified Ad plugin and the other is a Private Messaging plugin. Currently the Classified plugin only allows users to communicate by sending emails kinda like craigslist, however I want them to communicate internally on my site. So in the Classified plugin page, when I hit "reply to user" it shows me the Classified Ad's reply page. However at that point I want users to use the Private Messaging plugin so they can communicate on my site internally.

How do I direct the user to the Private Messaging plugin page AND have the Private Messaging plugin understand who both parties are? In other words, would something like this require more complicated programming skills with the use of filters and hooks...etc? I guess that's my real question.

Sorry for babbling on here, I'm just really reaching my limites of frustration with wordpress and have struggled to fully grasp the concept of WP.

In any case thank you beforehand
Brian

Comment: What exactly are the plugins that you are using? It's hard to judge what needs to be done when there is really no information on the capabilities of the plugins.

Comment: Riley the plugins are AWPCP and Cartpauj PM. However it's a question that can apply to any plugin. I guess I'm trying to understand how to move user data between different plugins so that the UX is seamless.

Comment: From what i saw on [awpcp.com](http://awpcp.com/classifieds/reply-to-ad/2935/sample-title/), there is already a "Reply to Add" option that does not disclose the email of the person who wrote the add. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because I want the users to stay on my site and communicate "internally". Otherwise the awpcp reply sends an email externally. Those are two completely different user experiences. In any case, any thoughts on my question regarding "moving user data between plugins"?

Comment: Well, I have an idea but you would need a decent knowledge in HTML, CSS, and PHP. My idea would be to locate the contact form in the AWPCP plugin and add the PMing plugin. If you want to learn programming I would recommend [codecademy.com](http://codecademy.com). Otherwise I would probably look for a plugin that has the two integrated, or hire out the job depending on your situation. I feel like it would be a great project to try and combine those plugins. Don't change the code on your live site though, make an offline version.

Comment: I'm creating a new Wordpress site and installing the plugins. Ill post my findings.

Comment: Riley that would be a tremendous help! Can't wait to hear back from you. Thank you!

Comment: Just to help you. In the PM plugin's "New Message" button you'll see an empty "to" field. I would want this form to already know which user is the recipient of the msg because the sender would have already hit the "reply" button in the classified ad post (other plugin). FYI the "Directory" button will be deleted/hidden, that is not useful for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I added a few lines of code to the "Cartpauj PM" plugin to add a new short code. I replaced the short code on the "Reply to Ad" page with the shorcode I created to bring up the new message tab of the Cartpauj PM plugin. The problem I am facing now is automatically adding the Ad owners name to the "To" field of the contact form. I will update you again when I figure that out, but for now, here is how to integrate the Cartpauj PM plugin. Below is a tutorial on how to change the messaging method. You can follow it, or make me a temporary account on your Wordpress and I'll do it for you. My tutorial is tested and works, but I do not want to be responsible for arising website issues should you do something incorrectly so edit at your own risk. Also keep in mind anytime you update this plugin, it will most likely delete all of the changes made.

**Step One**: Create the Shortcode

Go to the plugin editor and select the Cartpauj PM Plugin

[image: Selecting Cartpauj PM in the editor.]

After clicking the "Select" button, a new page will load. Scroll down in the editor until you see the following code:

```
//ADD SHORTCODES
add_shortcode('cartpauj-pm', array(&$cartpaujPMS, "displayAll"));
```

Then add a second line so it then looks like this:

```
//ADD SHORTCODES
add_shortcode('cartpauj-pm', array(&$cartpaujPMS, "displayAll"));
add_shortcode('cartpauj-new', array(&$cartpaujPMS, "newMessage"));
```

Click the "Update File" button.

**Step Two**: Define the "newMessage" short code

On the right side of your scene, click on the "cartpauj-pm/pm-class.php" link.

Then scroll down until you see code like this: 
(Close to the bottom underneath the /******************************************MAIN DISPLAY BEGIN******************************************/)

```
//Display the proper contents
    function displayAll()
    {
      global $user_ID;
      if ($user_ID)
      {
        //Finish the setup since these wouldn't work in the constructor
        $this->userOps = $this->getUserOps($user_ID);
        $this->setPageURLs();

        //Add header
        $out = $this->dispHeader();

        //Add Menu
        $out .= $this->dispMenu();

        //Start the guts of the display
        switch ($_GET['pmaction'])
        {
          case 'newmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispNewMsg();
            break;
          case 'checkmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispCheckMsg();
            break;
          case 'viewmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispReadMsg();
            break;
          case 'deletemessage':
            $out .= $this->dispDelMsg();
            break;
          case 'directory':
            $out .= $this->dispDirectory();
            break;
          case 'settings':
            $out .= $this->dispUserPage();
            break;
          case 'viewannouncements':
            $out .= $this->dispAnnouncement();
            break;
          default: //Message box is shown by Default
            $out .= $this->dispMsgBox();
            break;
        }



        //Add footer
        $out .= $this->dispFooter();
      }
      else
      {
        $out = "<p><strong>".__("You must be logged-in to view this page.", "cartpaujpm")."</strong></p>";
      }
      return $out;
    }
```

You are going to add some code underneath that function so it looks like the following:
(I recommend copy and pasting to avoid error)

```
//Display the proper contents
    function displayAll()
    {
      global $user_ID;
      if ($user_ID)
      {
        //Finish the setup since these wouldn't work in the constructor
        $this->userOps = $this->getUserOps($user_ID);
        $this->setPageURLs();

        //Add header
        $out = $this->dispHeader();

        //Add Menu
        $out .= $this->dispMenu();

        //Start the guts of the display
        switch ($_GET['pmaction'])
        {
          case 'newmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispNewMsg();
            break;
          case 'checkmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispCheckMsg();
            break;
          case 'viewmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispReadMsg();
            break;
          case 'deletemessage':
            $out .= $this->dispDelMsg();
            break;
          case 'directory':
            $out .= $this->dispDirectory();
            break;
          case 'settings':
            $out .= $this->dispUserPage();
            break;
          case 'viewannouncements':
            $out .= $this->dispAnnouncement();
            break;
          default: //Message box is shown by Default
            $out .= $this->dispMsgBox();
            break;
        }



        //Add footer
        $out .= $this->dispFooter();
      }
      else
      {
        $out = "<p><strong>".__("You must be logged-in to view this page.", "cartpaujpm")."</strong></p>";
      }
      return $out;
    }

//Display the new message
    function newMessage()
    {
      global $user_ID;
      if ($user_ID)
      {
        //Finish the setup since these wouldn't work in the constructor
        $this->userOps = $this->getUserOps($user_ID);
        $this->setPageURLs();

        //Add header
        $out = $this->dispHeader();

        //Add Menu
        $out .= $this->dispMenu();

        //Start the guts of the display
        switch ($_GET['pmaction'])
        {
          case 'newmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispNewMsg();
            break;
          case 'checkmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispCheckMsg();
            break;
          case 'viewmessage':
            $out .= $this->dispReadMsg();
            break;
          case 'deletemessage':
            $out .= $this->dispDelMsg();
            break;
          case 'directory':
            $out .= $this->dispDirectory();
            break;
          case 'settings':
            $out .= $this->dispUserPage();
            break;
          case 'viewannouncements':
            $out .= $this->dispAnnouncement();
            break;
          default: //Message box is shown by Default
            $out .= $this->dispNewMsg();
            break;
        }



        //Add footer
        $out .= $this->dispFooter();
      }
      else
      {
        $out = "<p><strong>".__("You must be logged-in to view this page.", "cartpaujpm")."</strong></p>";
      }
      return $out;
    }
```

Click the "Update File" button.

**Step Three**: Update the reply page.

Click the "Pages" tab on the leftmost Wordpress bar. Then open the page titled "Reply to Ad" (it will have a "-" in front of it).

Delete the current shortcut (but make a note of what the short code is somewhere on the backend so you don't forget it in the event you want to ever use it again), and replace it with the following:

```
[cartpauj-new]
```

Click "Update."

You are now done. The next step is automatically adding the recipient to the form which I will work on for you. I'm sorry this took so long to respond.

Comment: Riley no need to apologize. Your response is nothing short of amazing. You've certainly gone out of your way and I can't thank you enough. Now I'll have to sit down with a cup of coffee and pour over what you've written. You mention that updating the plugin will erase changes, so should I be adding this in a child theme of some sort? Can't wait for your other addition. Thank you again!

Comment: @YoYoMel Great idea. There is no such thing as a "child plugin." There are action hooks and filter hooks. I haven't really ever used those before, but it would definitely be the better, long term idea.

Comment: @YoYoMel The best bet would be to suggest this in the next plugin update and hope that the developer adds the feature. I will contact the plugin author. As far as automatically adding a user to the recipient field, it will take some work.